# Solr hit highlighting

Tags: solr

Can we get highlighter to replace original document field instead of creating new segment for highlighting?

Ex. Lets say my results has followings. I'm just trying to get *solr* within the doc itself without having to process separate highlighting segment. Not sure if i'm talking stupid according to how solr works.

```
<results>
<doc>
 <field1>this is solr test<field1>  
</doc>
</results>
<list name=highlighting>
 <list>
   <arr name=field1>
     <str>this is <em>solr</em>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, for now this is not possible out of the box with Solr.
Highlighting component is segregated and the processing for the highlighted text is handled separately.
For now you need to process it separately and the clients (solrj, rsolr or xsl) provide easy solutions for it.